# NodeJS Connect/Express implementation

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

Does anyone know how to implement the function chain used in connect/express. So one can do this..

```
var app = {}, app.stack = [];
app.use(function(r, s, n){
  // dosomething
})

require('http').createServer(function(r, s){
    // execute functions in app stack
})
```

Comment: You want to recreate the middleware stack of Connect/Express? If so: why?

Comment: Education. That func chain seems a useful pattern..

Comment: Well, a good starting point would be [`connect/lib/proto.js`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/proto.js), where `use` and `handle` are implemented.

Comment: ok thx.. was expecting some secret to recursion.. not really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware "chain" is actually just a "stack" which is actually a simple javascript Array of functions to execute in order. Whenever you call `use`, connect appends your function to the middleware stack. When it's time to run middleware, connect just executes all the functions in order with a bit of logic to pass the `req, res, next` parameters and wire up the `next` callback to mean continue processing the middleware stack. I agree with @robertklep that you should read the source code as it is quite readable and illuminating.